# CasperJS screenshot is not rendering images to png file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm successfully grabbing screenshots from multiple websites using phantomjs via casperjs. I'm having real problems though getting one site, http://fiver.com , to render out the background banner in this element:

```
<div class="hero-slide sel" style="background-image: url('//cdnil21.fiverrcdn.com/assets/v2_photos/sellerpage-coverphoto-779e2108b002090406e707086772ad9b.jpg');">
    <img alt="Sellerpage coverphoto" src="//cdnil21.fiverrcdn.com/assets/v2_photos/sellerpage-coverphoto-779e2108b002090406e707086772ad9b.jpg">
</div>
```

And then the first three images in `<div class="packages-list cf">` don't render either. The images following those render out to png just fine.

Versions being used:

- phantomjs: 1.9.8
- casperjs:  1.1.0-beta3

I'm using the following page settings for casperjs:

```
  pageSettings: {
javascriptEnabled: true,
loadImages: true,
loadPlugins: true,
localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true,
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
```

}
});

I'm loading the page, which is successfully redirecting to the https url. I'm running with this config file:

```
{"sslProtocol": "any", 
 "ignoreSslErrors": true, 
 "ssl-certificates-path": "ssl", 
 "web-security": false, 
 "cookiesFile": "biscuit", 
 "maxDiskCacheSize": 1000, "diskCache": true }
```

The code that executes and waits for everything to load is:

```
this.thenOpen(screenshotUrl, function() {
    this.wait(25000);

    // Fix transparent background rendering bug
    // Courtesy of: http://uggedal.com/journal/phantomjs-default-background-color/
    this.evaluate(function() {
        // css injection to force backgrounds to print
        var style = document.createElement('style'),
         text = document.createTextNode('body { background: #fff; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }');
        style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        style.appendChild(text);
        document.head.insertBefore(style, document.head.firstChild);

        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        images = Array.prototype.filter.call(images, function(i) { return !i.complete; });
        window.imagesNotLoaded = images.length;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function(i) {
            i.onload = function() { window.imagesNotLoaded--; };
        });
    });
});
casper.waitFor(function() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return window.imagesNotLoaded == 0;
    });
 });
 this.then(function(){
     this.echo('Screenshot for ' + viewport.name + ' (' + viewport.viewport.width + 'x' + viewport.viewport.height + ')', 'info');
     this.capture('screenshots/' + screenshotDateTime + '/' + viewport.name + '-' + viewport.viewport.width + 'x' + viewport.viewport.height + '.png', {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: viewport.viewport.width,
    height: viewport.viewport.height
    });
  });
```

I have tried setting the wait as high as 100000, but it still didn't work.In the evaluate I'm injecting some css and running a function that is trying to wait for all the images to load. Thn I go into my this.then function to render the image to disk.

I'm pulling my hair out with this one.

Here's the screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/flvpvhy6v/

Any ideas?

Comment: Show how does you code look like currently. Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot of what CasperJS currently renders would be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, added code. You to Jeffrey, couldn't post image here, not enough rep.

Comment: What comes after (all the way down to the callback) `this.wait(5000);`? If it is something other than `then*` or `wait*`, you have to put it in a step. Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Hi Artjom B. I've added the entire code block above.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has no blocking wait or sleep functionality. So when you `wait`, you schedule an asynchronous step. Your code contains an `evaluate` call after the `wait` call. The `evaluate` call is synchronous/blocking, but `wait` isn't, so the `wait` will be executed after the `evaluate`. You have to put synchronous code in a callback of a step function like `wait*` or `then*`.

```
this.wait(25000, function(){
    this.evaluate(function() {
        // some code
    });
});
```